# how do i search for an entry in mongodb database using java in netbeans?

Tags: java, mongodb, search, netbeans

I have made a database in Mongodb and a collection with a few entries.I want to search for an entry using Java and also display it. I'm using Netbeans as my IDE. I tried searching all over the internet but couldn't find anything relevant. I'm new to Java and Mongodb.

Comment: Try reading http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DBObject result = new Mongo().getDb("yourDatabaseName").getCollection("yourTableName").findOne(new BasicDBObject("id", id), new BasicDBObject("specialColumn", 1));
return result.get("specialColumn")
```

This example will search for the field "specialColumn" in the collection "yourTableName" with the id "id"! 
There are more methods provided like .find(), where you can process with a DBCursor to check the results!

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/